# BlueprintJS is not loading its icon CSS module, but is able to load the core CSS module

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, blueprint

I'm learning to incorporate BlueprintJS into my React web app, and having a lot of trouble loading in some of the CSS modules.

I've installed `npm install @blueprintjs/core` and `npm install react-transition-group`.

The BlueprintJS [Getting Started Docs](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v2/#blueprint/getting-started) say to load in the CSS files like this:

```
 // or, using node-style package resolution in a CSS file: 
 @import "~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";
 @import "~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css";
```

I'm currently using `webpack` for my build tool, so I've included the following configurations in my `webpack.config.js`:

However, when I attempt to build my `bundle.js`, I receive this error message when including the `~@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css` file:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@blueprintjs/icons/resources/icons/icons-16.eot
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/@blueprintjs/icons/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css 7:296-341
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./js/styles/styles.scss
 @ ./js/styles/styles.scss
 @ ./js/app.js
 @ multi ./js/app.js
```

I do not, however, receive this error when importing in the core `blueprint.css` file. The error message appears to be suggesting that my loaders are having trouble parsing the `~` symbbol. However, I don't understand why it has no issue parsing the line right before it (`@import "~@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css";`).

Could someone steer me in the right direction for why this error is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at exactly where the error was coming from (`./node_modules/@blueprintjs/icons/resources/icons/icons-16.eot`), I realized that webpack wasn't able to load in `.eot` files, hence the `Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)` error message.

The issue here for me was not having the appropriate loaders. There are a bunch of `.eof` and `.woff` files that Blueprint uses internally that need special loaders (`file-loader` and `url-loader`).

```
  {
    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: 'fonts/[hash].[ext]',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
      name: 'fonts/[hash].[ext]',
      limit: 5000,
      mimetype: 'application/font-woff',
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have just had the same problem and Yu Chen's answered resolved it for me.  Thank you!